# Ember load async property

Tags: ember.js

in my ember app I want to load images. My model has serveral images, so I load them asynchonously.

```
fotos: DS.hasMany('foto', { async: true })
```

Each 'foto' has a proptery to the file location 'fileName: DS.attr()'. Now, in the controller of my route in need to extend the path to load the image as a background image:

```
loadImage: function(){
    var path;
    this.get('model').forEach(function(art){
        art.get('fotos').then(function(fotos){
            path = fotos.get('content')[0].get('fileName');
        })
    });
    return "background-image:url(" + path +")";
}.property()
```

(the log says) loadImage or path contains the correct path of the image. In my template when I try to render it with {{loadImage}} it never appears. How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

path is being set asynchronously, and you are returning an empty value immediately.

```
firstImagePath: Em.computed.alias('firstObject.fotos.fileName'), // this assumes you're in an ArrayController

loadImage: function(){
    var path = this.get('firstImagePath');
    return "background-image:url(" + path +")";
}.property('firstImagePath')
```

Comment: many thanks for the answer. I already tried that because I needed the alias thing in another template. The image is rendered there, but in the (array)controller the firstImagePath is always null :(